# Using keyboard shortcuts with the Super (windows) key in Linux Mint Mate

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, linux-mint

I'm using Linux Mint 15. I'm using the keyboard shortcut "Super_L" to open the Mint menu of the Mate desktop.

Now I want to use for example the shortcut "Super_L+1" to open a terminal window. I went to Menu->Control Center->Keyboard Shortcuts and assigned the proper key combination to "Open a terminal window". It shows up as "Mod4+1".

Having done that, pressing "Super_L+1" has this strange behavior:
1st press: opens mint menu
2nd press: opens terminal
3rd press: opens mint menu
...

The shortcut works every other key press which is very annoying. Is there a way to reliably use such shortcuts?

I only found this thread which mentions the same issue but doesn't give a working solution
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=55&t=31550

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. What I've done is mapped the Menu key (the one that opens context menus) to open the Mint menu. I don't use that key anyways, and you can always use Shift + F10 to get the same effect.

Then I was able to map key shortcuts with the Windows (Super) key without a problem.

Comment: I haven't found any better answer either so I'll accept yours. It's too bad though there's no other way!

Answer (score 6):

I did almost the same as Bojan suggested. I have Linux Mint 17 Mate.

However, the Mint Menu hotkey is not listed in MATE's *Keyboard Shortcuts* dialog.

If you right click on the Mint Menu applet, and select *Preferences*, then on the first tab, you can select another hotkey to replace *<Super_L>*, or if you just want to remove that hotkey at all, you can press backspace.

Comment: nice, that works!

Answer (score 2):

This problem was annoying me as well. I never use the Super key for the start menu, anyway, and opening a terminal is much more important to me. I solved the annoyance by opening the following file:

/usr/share/mint-configuration-xfce/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml

It contains the following line:

```
<property name="Super_L" type="string" value="xfce4-popup-whiskermenu"/>
```

I changed it as follows:

```
<property name="&lt;Super&gt;m" type="string" value="xfce4-popup-whiskermenu"/>
```

And added another line underneath:

```
<property name="&lt;Super&gt;t" type="string" value="xfce4-terminal"/>
```

(Don't forget to restart the operating system after making the changes.)

Now I can still open the start menu if I want to via Super+M, but the Super key does not interfere with Super+T anymore. (If you don't need a shortcut for the start menu at all, just remove the entire line.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, though it's strange to have to go root just to remove a keyboard shortcut. It was not needed on Linux mint 17.2 XFCE edition, I found that the Super_L shortcut does appear in the keyboard shortcut list, can be removed and has the intended effect, permanently.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here.  I finally solved it. The small tool [ksuperkey](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php/ksuperkey?content=154569), which has been developed for KDE, works perfect with other desktops.

In Xfce, I bound whiskermenu to "alt-f1" and put ksuperkey into autostart.  Do the same for the application launcher you're using in Mate. The super key will behave as one would expect.